# What is the django way to print debug messages?

Tags: python, django, debugging

Suppose I have this function in `views.py` in Django.

```
def test_func(request, username):
    print("print debug msg in test_func()")
    # other code 
    return
```

Using `print()` doesn't look like a good way to print out debug messages because the messages will be printed out even in production mode. How do I write debug messages on Django so that the messages will only be printed out in DEBUG mode?

I am using Django 4.1

EDIT: Since the question is closed, I will write my own answer here.
Credit goes to https://www.containiq.com/post/django-logging
This is what I did.

In `settings.py`,

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = None

LOGLEVEL = os.environ.get('LOGLEVEL', 'info').upper()

logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            # exact format is not important, this is the minimum information
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        },
        'django.server': DEFAULT_LOGGING['formatters']['django.server'],
    },
    'handlers': {
        # console logs to stderr
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
        'django.server': DEFAULT_LOGGING['handlers']['django.server'],
    },
    'loggers': {
        # default for all undefined Python modules
        '': {
            # 'level': 'WARNING',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
        # Our application code
        'app': {
            'level': LOGLEVEL,
            'handlers': ['console'],
            # Avoid double logging because of root logger
            'propagate': False,
        },
        # Default runserver request logging
        'django.server': DEFAULT_LOGGING['loggers']['django.server'],
    },
})
```

In `views.py`,

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# example to print out log msg. 
# logger.info("debug_message")
```

Comment: You’d use the Python native `logging` module and configure the logging levels in your Django settings.

Comment: Django has a logging framework for this.